# Unlimited Multiselect Attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation, multiselect-attribute

I have a Magento Webshop (CE 1.9) where I use a multi-select attribute. There seems to be a maximum number of multi-select options I can actually select in the product. I've read about a solution changing the backend_type from varchar to text. That works, but after that change the attribute is not showing on the layered navigation. Is there another solution?

Comment: After you changed the backend_type, have you checked that the problem still have the values after all? Or have you transfered all values from catalog_product_entity_varchar to catalog_product_entity_text?

Comment: Yes. The old values where still there. Also selected within the product. The ones selected during 'varchar' where also still available in layered nav. The ones selected during 'text' where not in layered nav.